# Android app to compare prices

Tags: android, shopping-cart

I'm looking for an Android app to compare prices of any item.  Would like to see online and brick-and-mortar prices.

The types of items I am interested in are a full range of consumer items.  Examples: rechargeable batteries, toasters, cameras, tools, engine oil, etc.  Basically, anything that a major online (like Amazon) or brick-and-mortar retailer sells.

So far, I have found RedLaser, but it often does not have the item and when it does, only lists 1 or 2 stores selling it.

What do you recommend?

Comment: This will need some more details, e.g. what "items"? There are several apps available to [Compare Prices](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_deals#group_296), but many of them are dedicated to specific product groups (food, drugs, etc.) or regions (US, EU, or even specific countries).

Comment: @Izzy Thank you for your comment.  I've updated the question per your request.  That's quite a list of sites you have; is it all created by hand?  Are the permissions automatically updated as new versions change required permissions?  Is there an English version?

Comment: Many questions :) Handmade and maintained, yes – but updated automatically and regularly, including *added* permissions (*revoked* ones are dealt with manually, in case the API fails ;) And yes: Click the English flag, or have your browser settings include the "en" language preference ;) /// Thanks for updating your post. Could you also add the "region" which *must* be covered (plus optionally "nice-to-have-covered)? From *RedLaser* I deduce US, but better put that explicitly :)

Answer (score 2):

#### [Google Shopper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.shopper)

Product search/comparison via Google Shopping. Just scan/speak/snap and you can search Googles database for the product. You can see the prices among Google Shopping partner retailers along with ratings and reviews.

#### [PriceGrabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pricegrabber.PGAndroid)

More of a focus on online retailers as opposed to physical retail locations but it tells you if the item is available online somewhere for less.

#### [ShopSavvy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.biggu.shopsavvy&hl=en)

Compares brick-and-mortar stores with online retailers and even includes shipping prices so you can compare what you would pay.You can just scan the barcode and get the lowest prices. ShopSavvy also allows you to get alerted on any search and you can browse sales from top retailers.

> What do you recommend?

I would recommend ShopSavvy. I've used all three of these at some point and ShopSavvy always had the best results for what I was searching. They also have alerts for searches which the other two AFAIK do not have.

Comment: PriceGrabber seeems to be gone.